# Elequent orm 3 table relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 table

```
exam(id,final_id) final(id,report_id) report(id)
```

How can i get report of exam with elequent orm?

In exam MODEL

```
public function final()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(FINAL::class, 'id', 'final_id');
}
```

in Controller

```
$data = exam::with('final')->get();
```

But how can i write `FINAL` and `REPORT` relationship with these fields?

Answer (score 0):

In Final Model define:

```
public function report() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Report::class); 
}
```

do

```
$exam = Exam::find(1);
$final = $exam->final;
$report = $final->report;
```

Comment: `$examlist=EXAM::select('id','final_id')->with(['final'=>function($q){
                return  $q->with('report:id')->select('*');
            }])->get();`

  This is full correct form